# t-test for control and test group pre and post where pre and post subjects differ

Tags: paired-comparisons

I have been asked to help in analysing an educational intervention that has been completed, with a control and test group, pre and post tests to evaluate the effect of an intervention. It seems the usual t test for paired comparison cannot be used because the students in the pre and post were not the same, i.e. samples are from the same populations / same set of schools (those receiving the intervention and those not) but not the same students?? So I cannot work out a mean difference per pupil, just in aggregate. Can anyone advise what analysis method to use. 
The data is test scores for the 4 groups, pre control, pre test, post control, post test??

Comment: I think one can do unpaired t-test between pre values of control and test groups and if there is no significant difference, do unpaired t-test between 2 post values to see if test intervention has any significant effect. If there is a significant difference between pre values from 2 groups, then (postmean - premean) differences (i.e. deltas) in control and treatment groups can be compared using unpaired t-test. But I do not know what would be the SD here? It may be as on this page: http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node81.html

Comment: Thank you, yes that was my problem. I did not know how to find the SD or SE of the difference in means. The reference you give seems to solve it.